# girls vs guys for core strength

Tags: core

Guys are supposed to have more upper body strength than girls but what about core strength? Seems like yoga, pilates, pole dancing and the like utilize the core much more so than biceps or chest or anything.

Comment: I honestly think that the measure of core strength is gender independent, as it rather depends on the persons individual level of fitness.

Comment: What do yoga, pilates, and pole dancing have to do with this question?

Comment: This question is off topic, if it were asked with more details and maybe a source for the claim I would ignore that, but in its current form I there is too much gender stereotyping.

Comment: @Kate - those activities seem to be more female dominated than male dominated and as such I'd kinda expect them to cater to their perceived strengths.

Answer (score 2):

It's a misconception that males have stronger upper bodies, as opposed to general strengtha all around the body generally being stronger:

http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/human-biology/men-vs-women-upper-body-strength.htm

http://www.livestrong.com/article/422532-do-women-have-more-lower-body-strength-than-men/

Comment: Can you summarize some of the information and quote it here rather than just posting links?